# Confused in working with isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a problem from Fraleigh, *Abstract Algebra*, 7th Ed.

> The map $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\phi(n)=n+1$ for 
>   $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is one to one and onto. Give the definition of the binary operation $*$ such that $\phi$ is an isomorphism mapping
>
> a. $\langle \mathbb{Z},+ \rangle$ onto $\langle \mathbb{Z},* \rangle$
>
> b. $\langle \mathbb{Z},* \rangle$ onto $\langle \mathbb{Z},+ \rangle$
>
> In each case, give the identity element $*$ for $ \mathbb{Z}$.

My question is in part b. but for reference here is what I did for the whole exercise.

a. For $\phi$ being a isomorphism, we must fulfill $\phi(m+n)=\phi(m)*\phi(n)$. Thus $\phi(m+n)=m+n+1$. On the other hand: $\phi(n)*\phi(m)=(n+1)*(m+1)$, and therefore $m+n+1=(n+1)*(m+1)-1$, thus, the operation $*$ has to be $n+m-1$.

For the identity, in $\langle \mathbb{Z},+ \rangle$ the identity is zero, thus $\phi(0)=1$.

b. Since $\phi$ is bijective, the inverse $\phi^{-1}$ exists and it is given by $\phi^{-1}(n)=n-1$.

Thus

$$
m*n = \phi^{-1}(m+1)*\phi^{-1}(n+1)=\phi^{-1}(m+n+2)=m+n+1.
$$

First question: why the operation changes, i.e. why in a. we have $m*n=m+n-1$, and in b. $m+n+1$?

Second question: for b. the identity has to be $-1$. What confuses me is the answer in the book, which says that $-1=\phi^{-1}(0)$, should not be $\phi^{-1}(-1)=0$? I know the answer should be correct, but it confuses me because $\phi^{-1}:*\rightarrow+$, which tells me that if I want to know an element from $*$ in $+$, I have to use the function $\phi^{-1}$